# interchange integral and inf

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be the unit sphere on $\mathbb{R}^n$, A be a positive define diagonal $n\times n$ matrix, and $\mu$ is a probabilistic measure on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. So is it correct to interchange the integral and inf on the following expression:
$$\int_{\mathbb{S}^n\ \ } \inf_{y\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}\Big( y^TAy-2\langle x,y\rangle \Big)d\mu(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

No. Integral of an infimum is less than or equal to the infimum of the integrals but equality holds only in very special cases.

Comment: What about this particular case?

Comment: Why is the integral of an infimum less than or equal to the infimum of the intregals?